# Not able to use opencv4nodejs in Next.js

Tags: node.js, opencv, next.js

The opencv4nodejs module is working fine but when I integrate it with next.js, it is showing the following error --

```
Error in ./utils
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/yathartharora/Certificate/node_modules/opencv-build/build
```

When I run my OpenCV part separately it is working fine but as soon as I import it in my index.js it shows an error. Can someone please help me in resolving this

Comment: `opencv4nodejs` is a Node.js library, and only works on the server. It looks like you're trying to use it in client-side code. Can you show us the code where you're using it?